# Excel: Compare multiple columns to see if less than value in another column for all rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am trying to compare data across multiple columns to see if each cell is less than a value in a single cell on the same row.

[image: What my spreadsheet looks like]

Column B contains the mean across all employees for the variable in Column A (there are 12 variables). Columns C through N contain the mean for each individual employee. For each of the variables, I would like to highlight the cell for employees whose mean is less than the mean of all employees.

I can figure out how to do this for each row (compare the values in columns C through N with the value in column B) using conditional formatting using a formula:

```
If Cell Value is <$B$2, apply highlighting to =$C$2:$N$2.
```

I don't want to have to do this row by row if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the data from C2 to N13. Create a new conditional formatting rule with a formula. Use this formula

```
=C2<$B2
```

and apply a format. Note the placement of the dollar signs. As the conditional format is applied across and down, the reference `C2` will be adjusted to whatever the current cell is. The comparison will always look at column B, since the $ sign makes the column an absolute reference, whereas the row number will adjust to the current row.

If you want to use the Highlight Cell rules dialog, just change the $B$2 to $B2 and apply the format to $C$2:$N$13